# Intermittent Electricity Output - Causal Effects

Tags: regression, causality, zero-inflation, intermittent-time-series, armax

I am working on modeling the electricity output of a single power plant.

More specifically, I am trying to compute causal effects of a variable *prop* on *output*. My model would look something like this

$$
output = \beta_0 + \beta_1 prob + \boldsymbol{d}'\boldsymbol{X} + u
$$
where I omit the time index $t$ for brevity. The covariate vector $X$ can include lags of the dependent variable.

The problem I have is that the dependent variable seems like it could be an intermittent time series, which would render a classic modeling approach unsuitable. The periods with subsequent zeros are different in duration they do not follow each other in a constant frequency.

Consider the figure below, where the blue line represents the original data and the red line the predicted values of a model that includes nine lagged terms of the dependent variable. It is quite obvious that the ARX model I chose does not consider the zero-bound, which would render my estimate of $\beta_1$ unreliable.

I have read about approaches like Croston's method or INARMA. However, they seem to focus completely on forecasting, which is not the goal here. How can I estimate the model such that it follows the true data generating process and estimates a reliable value for the parameter of interest?

[image]

The variables were transformed using the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation in order to smooth the variance. This explains the units of measurement.

Many thanks in advance!